# Are there any valid use case for using public variables in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, oop, variables, getter-setter

Variable encapsulation, Set/Get methods are best practices but why do we have a chance to declare a variable public if it's not meant to be used anyway? Would it have been better if variables were always private by default with no chance of making them public since all of the tutorials I read says they should be encapsulated with set/get methods? Is there any valid use case for public variables at least in PHP OOP?

Comment: there are use cases for protected variables in classes (e.g. inheritance / overwriting), but i don't know of any for public ones. that might be due to the php 4 var $var declaration in classes which is interpreted as public in php 5.

Comment: Simple answer: because there are various perfectly valid reasons for **not** (wanting) to use getters and setters, so you can simply access the public variables.

Comment: @CodeCaster in most cases of dynamic oop that shows bad design i think.

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax Its just an RFC, but I hope it will be in PHP 5.5 :)

Comment: @KingCrunch That link is arguably the best possible answer to this question, as it outlines exactly the pros and cons of what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact it's just the other way round: Theoretically getters/setters are *wrong*. The properties defines the state of an object, where the methods defines the behaviour. Getters/Setters only intercept the read and write access to properties, but they break the semantic meaning completely: Now reading the status of an object is a behaviour of the object.

To make properties to look like properties again there is a RFC on the road :)
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax

Answer (score 1):

> Set/Get methods are best practices but why do we have a chance to declare a variable public if it's not meant to be used anyway?

Best practices and not meant to be used is not the same. A language needs to offer different tools for different use-cases and should be consistent.

PHP objects always supported public members and when differentiated visibility was introduced, for backwards compatible reasons public members are very useful.

> Would it have been better if variables were always private by default with no chance of making them public since all of the tutorials I read says they should be encapsulated with set/get methods?

That question can not be specifically answered, it's too subjective and there are too many different use-cases that would result in a different answers.

> Is there any valid use case for public variables at least in PHP OOP?

Start with backwards compatiblity. If you can not refactor your code but would need to rewrite it completely all the time, this would be very expensive.

Answer (score -1):

let's see..
this's a real world Email API class from [CakePHP EmailComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1284/Class-Attributes-and-Variables). to use this class you only need to "set" some property then just `send()`

```
$this->Email->to = 'ss@b.co';
$this->Email->from = 'me@b.co';
$this->Email->title = 'xxx';
$this->Email->msg = 'blabla..';
$this->Email->send();
```

in fact there is a lot of private properties and function inside this class but it's private.

**Class** has (single) responsibility to do something.
**Encapsulation** is to publish only what people use to do that thing and keep technical/infrastructure inside as **private**.